# Why it is showing No such column

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

```
/* Triggers*/
create table acustomer( id integer primary key, desc text, last_order_id integer);
create table bcustomer ( id integer primary key, item_id int, customer_id int, quan int, price int);
insert into acustomer (desc) values ( 'rohan');
insert into acustomer (desc) values ('mohan');
insert into acustomer (desc) values ('sohan');
select * from acustomer;
create trigger ccustomer after insert on bcustomer
begin
    update acustomer set last_order_id = NEW.id where acustomer.id = NEW.customer_id;
end;
insert into bcustomer (item_id, customer_id, quan, price) values (1, 2, 3, 4);
insert into bcustomer (item_id, customer_id, quan, price) values (5, 6, 7, 8);
insert into bcustomer (item_id, customer_id, quan, price) values (8, 9, 10, 20);
insert into bcustomer (item_id, customer_id, quan, price) values (4, 12, 19, 13);

select * from acustomer;
select * from bcustomer;
```

#On executing insertion in table ccustomer, it is showing error : no such column : NEW.customer.id

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? Where is the "table ccustomer"? Also, you wrote " no such column : NEW.customer.id", whereas your code shows it as `NEW.customer_id`

Comment: Hi shahkalpesh.. No such column is a error code that is showing while inserting into bcustomer.

Answer (score 0):

Your last insert for **bcustomer** table is

```
insert into bcustomer (item_id, customer_id, quan, price) values (4, 12, 19, 13);
```

which doesn't have any matching **last_order_id** in acustomer.

If you will run

```
insert into bcustomer (item_id, customer_id, quan, price) values (4, 1, 19, 13);
```

**customer_id = 1**, it will update your **acustomer** table since it has a matching id, which is **1**.

try this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f694ba340c97e57746a75423fde5e015).

Comment: Hello, Ed Bangga, 
Perfect. it worked. Thank you.